# How to compile Objective-C code in Visual Studio

Tags: objective-c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have an old project which is written in Objective-C. There were some in-house compilers written to compile from Objective-C to C code. However due to some compatibility issues those compilers aren't working anymore.

In Build 2015, Microsoft demonstrated building some objective-c code (.m) projects in Visual Studio. However I can't find the steps to do them.

Looking for the steps for the same. I have Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 both.

Comment: I found the demo [here] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nK0SaMbuwrQ&t=1842s) which would be useful for you. The whole idea is to re-use the objective c code that is developed for iOS on Universal Windows Platform(UWP) app development.I couldn't find the exact steps either.

Comment: Yes, this is the broadcast of **Build 2015**. This just demoes the feature but doesn't tell how to do. I mean, do i need to install any extension or link to any libraries. That's what I am trying to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly believe you are talking about the **WinObjC**, the Windows bridge for iOS. It is an open-source project that provides an Objective-C development environment for Visual Studio and support for iOS APIs.

You have to install To Chocolatey & winobjc-tools to get started with an existing Xcode Project. The installation details are here : [WinObjC Download and Installation](https://github.com/microsoft/WinObjC)

Comment: Actually, this library I had already come across. I was thinking somehow MS has included the support in VS 2015 by default or at least in VS 2017, may be in Xamarin or UWP.

Comment: Upon using this tool, I could generate the sln and vcxproj files. However I am getting thousands of compilation errors. Could you tell which version of Clang or Objective-C it supports? Because my code was written around 1995. I suspect some version mismatch.

Comment: If it is written around 1995, better to re-write the entire code instead of improving the existing code. There are major changes happened after 1995 especially to the compilers and IDE's. Example: The ARC is introduced by the LLVM 3.0 compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have that much amount of time to re-write the code. Regarding the ARC, few things make sense now. I am constantly getting few errors relating to this ARC.

Comment: you can turn off the ARC of required.

Comment: 1995? You definitely need to turn off ARC.  Do your classes at least inherit from NSObject, or do they inherit from the old Object superclass ?  If the latter... that will be difficult with today's compilers.

Comment: They inherit from NSObject. How can I turn-off ARC. Is there a way to make the modern compiler to run in a previous version using some kind of flag or something

Comment: Normally it's turned *on* via the -fobjc-arc flag to clang.  It can be turned off with the -fno-objc-arc flag (sometimes particular files need that, which override the default).  I don't know if you are using clang -- I'm not familiar with the WinObjC project.  If it's NSObject code, then it should mostly be fine compiling in non-ARC mode I'd think today.  There will be a number of methods which have been deprecated, and in a couple places removed, but most of the methods on the classes then still exist today.